# spring data jpa process large result set in batches

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

In my code below I am iterating over a large result set and I want to save to the `orderRepository` JPA repository in batches. How would I go about doing this.

```
@Repository
public class FruitRepo {

    private JdbcTemplate template;
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    public FruitRepo(JdbcTemplate template, OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.template = template;
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }


    public static final String GROUP_BY_FRUIT_SQL = "select name, count(*), order_id " +
            "from fruit where order_id = ?" +
            "group by name, order_id";


    public void insertRecords(Integer orderId) {
        template.query(GROUP_BY_FRUIT_SQL, ps -> ps.setInt(1, orderId),  new RowCallbackHandler() {
            @Override
            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                List<Orders> orders = new ArrayList<>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String description = ""; // to apply business logic
                    Orders order = Orders.builder()
                            .name(rs.getString(1))
                            .count(rs.getInt(2))
                            .description(description)
                            .orderId(rs.getInt(3)).build();
                    orders.add(order);
                }
                // want to save in batches of 50
                orderRepository.saveAll(orders);

            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can add a count variable and save after the count=50 or you can use pagination and fetch 50 rows from db while select query.

Comment: i'm not sure if you'd want to put this kind of logic in your repository.  this seems more like something you'd want to do in the service layer, but i'm also a little lost on what/why you're trying to accomplish

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65116990/how-to-persist-data-to-a-mysql-database-from-a-32k-row-excel-using-jpa-paginatio/65121125#65121125